# jQuery hide inner html, except for a tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="content-body attribute-pdf">
<a href="/_fragment/content/download/296/1935/file/blabla.pdf">
blabla.pdf</a> 1.2 Mb
</div>
```

This is coming out of a CMS, and I would like to hide this "1.2 MB",but still keep the A href part

is this possible to do in jQuery ?

I tried this:

```
$(".attribute-pdf").children().hide();
```

which hides the A href, but still shows the text. I want it vice-versa - hide the text, but still show the A href.

Comment: or completely remove the text is also not a problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick way, in jQuery - empty the div, replace its contents with *just* the `<a>` tag:

```
$('.attribute-pdf').each(
  function() {
    var container = $(this);
    var a = container.find('a').detach();
    container.empty().append(a);   
  }
);
```

Example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/iaFnK

Comment: perfect! thanks! indeed it should work on multiple divs, and this was the best solution

Answer (score 1):

You could set the contents of the parent to be the contents of the childeren ...

```
$(".attribute-pdf").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this); // cache for performance
    $this.html($this.children());
});
```

Comment: That will be problematic if there's more than one `.attribute-pdf` div.

Answer (score 1):

grab the content ( a link ) , empty the div ( removes 1.2 mb )    and again append a link.

http://jsfiddle.net/vpVMK/

```
    var content = $(".attribute-pdf a");
    $(".attribute-pdf").html(''); 
    $(".attribute-pdf").append(content);
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do:

```
// contents() gives children, all including non-element nodes.
// Then, we can filter those down to the final text one.
var textNodes = $( ".attribute-pdf" ).contents().filter(function() { 
    return this.nodeType === 3; 
});

var lastTextNode = textNodes.last();
//and replace 
lastTextNode.replaceWith('');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
var children = $(".attribute-pdf").children();
$(".attribute-pdf").html(children);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H2WVt/

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method that hasn't been posted yet:

```
$(".attribute-pdf").html(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        $tmp = $('<div>');

    return $.makeArray( $this.children('a').map(function() {
        $tmp.html(this)
        return $tmp[0].innerHTML
    }) ).join('')
})
```

The **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4359d/)**